# Invalid Syntax Print Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def datos_velocidad_turbohelice(incremento):
    velocidadInicial = 181.3566
    aceleraciónInicial = 3 - 0.000062 *(velocidadInicial**2)
    print('Tiempo   '+ 'Velocidad(m/s)   '+ 'Aceleracion(m/s**2) '+'\n')
    print ('0       '+ str(velocidadInicial) + str(aceleraciónInicial))
    tiempo=incremento
    while tiempo <= 130:
     velocidadIncremento= (0.00001(tiempo**3)) - (0.00488(tiempo**2)) + (0.75795(tiempo)) + 181.3566
     aceleracionIncremento= 3 - (0.000062 *(velocidadIncremento**2)
     print (str(tiempo)+str(velocidadIncremento)+str(aceleracionIncremento))
     tiempo+= incremento
datos_velocidad_turbohelice(20)
```

my question is where is the error? it says
    print (str(tiempo)+str(velocidadIncremento)+str(aceleracionIncremento))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Not sure why it would point to that line, but two lines above there are errors: by `0.00001(...)` I suppose you mean `0.00001 * (...)`, etc.

Comment: it points the t in print im sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors here.

For one, the SyntaxError you are initially describing impacting this line, `(str(tiempo)+str(velocidadIncremento)+str(aceleracionIncremento))` is not actually involving this line but rather the line above it, `aceleracionIncremento= 3 - (0.000062 *(velocidadIncremento**2)`; you are missing a closing parenthesis there at the end.

Once you fix this error you will encounter another error (a TypeError) stating that the `'float' object is not callable`, to which you will need to address by fixing this line `velocidadIncremento=(0.00001*(tiempo**3)) - (0.00488*(tiempo**2)) + (0.75795*(tiempo)) + 181.3566` by adding an `*` operator to multiply the `0.75795` by `tiempo`. This should fix the code.

Full fix below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def datos_velocidad_turbohelice(incremento):
    velocidadInicial = 181.3566
    aceleracionInicial = 3 - 0.000062 *(velocidadInicial**2)
    print('Tiempo   '+ 'Velocidad(m/s)   '+ 'Aceleracion(m/s**2) '+'\n')
    print('0       '+ str(velocidadInicial) + str(aceleracionInicial))
    tiempo=incremento
    while tiempo <= 130:
     velocidadIncremento=(0.00001*(tiempo**3)) - (0.00488*(tiempo**2)) + (0.75795*(tiempo)) + 181.3566
     aceleracionIncremento= 3 - (0.000062 *(velocidadIncremento**2))
     print(str(tiempo)+str(velocidadIncremento)+str(aceleracionIncremento))
     tiempo+= incremento
datos_velocidad_turbohelice(20)
```

*Output*:

```
Tiempo   Velocidad(m/s)   Aceleracion(m/s**2)

0       181.35660.960806585459
20194.64360.6510598767
40204.50660.406977134499
60211.42560.228551371208
80215.88060.110525125706
100218.35160.0439998842013
120219.31860.0177598050305
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . I noticed after a while.

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax error in line number `8` and `9`. You need to add `*` before the brackets and in line number `9` you added an extra bracket which you did not close.

```
 velocidadIncremento= (0.00001*(tiempo**3)) - (0.00488*(tiempo**2)) + (0.75795*(tiempo)) + 181.3566
 aceleracionIncremento= 3 - 0.000062 *(velocidadIncremento**2)
```